# WooCommerce custom payment gateway integration not doing POST

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I'm wondering if you could help me. I'm working on a custom payment gateway integration with WooCommerce and I'm stuck now. The moment I click on pay I get a 500 Internal Server error in Chromes console and it gets stuck in the receipt page.

You can check the code I got so far here

https://github.com/tora-soft/visanet-uy-payment-gateway/blob/master/visanet-uy-payment-gateway.php

It is supposed to generate an html form and make a POST to the payment gateway where the user would enter his/her CC details and then come back. **This is working now**

**UPDATE Aug 15th**

Now the post is working but when coming back from the payment gateway is landing on a default checkout page and is not processing the result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: @Anand I use godaddy shared hosting and there is nothing on the php error log. I've set up the plugin to save some logs when running each of the functions and for some reason is not executing the receipt_page, which is the one that generates the form and makes the post even though I've added to the actions.

Comment: @Anand Sorry I deleted the question by accident. Now the POST is working but when coming back is not processing the payment. Nothing on the error log.

Comment: Can you confim if OpenSSL extension is enabled on your server? I downloaded your code and went as far the auto redirection but since I don't have the private key I cannot test it further.

Comment: @Anand It is enabled, not using 443 for the transactions though. I'm using standard port 80. If I check the network on Google Chrome and see the headers I get a POST response correctly from the server when coming back to the shop but the shop is not processing the result.

Comment: Have tried enabling debug mode?

Comment: @Anand Yes but there is no error at all. I even enabled the woocommerce log on this integration so it logs to a txt file each time it executes one of it's functions like paypal does and the response function is not being executed.

Answer (score 4):

@Federico You should not rely on the user pressing "return to website" to receive the payment response payload.  you should rely on the IPN response talk from their backend to your backend.  your payment provider tells the user the payment is successful and the user closes the browser.

Step 1. When redirecting the user to the VisaNetUY, make it return back on the Thank You URL.

```
$return_url = $this->get_return_url($order);
```

Step 2. Give this URL to your payment gateway so that it can notify your website when a transaction has approved. (sometimes known as webhook or ipn response)

```
http://myurl.com/?wc-api=WC_VisaNetUY
```

Step 3. You need to remove this line.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'check_response'  ));
```

Step 4. and use this line instead:

```
add_action('woocommerce_api_wc_visanetuy', array($this, 'check_response') ); 
//the WC_VisaNetUY from step2 url gets converted to lowercase by wordpress and appended to woocommerce_api_, and if it matches then it calls your function name, in this case it calls your 'check_response', but you could have put any function name here instead of check_reponse in fact some people call it handle_callback or check_ipn_response.
```

Step 5. Don't call $order->reduce_order_stock() because $order->payment_complete() already does the reducing stock, and changing status for you.